# How to increase max client body size Google Cloud Endpoints GKE

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

A large POST request to my endpoints cluster returns a "413 Request Entity Too Large" error. I realize that the NGINX conf has a limit set at 32mb, but how can I modify that, given that I am using GKE.

The link, https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/kubernetes-concept, describes how to do it with a pure K8's cluster, but that does not seem to work in a GKE environment.

In that case, my esp container says that it cannot find /etc/nginx/custom/trusted-ca-certificates.crt.

So, basically, how do I increase the max client body size for Google Cloud Endpoints running on GKE?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have created [a github issue](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-tools/issues/38)

to add a flag to change Nginx client_max_body_size.

Please watch  [ESP release note](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/releases)